# long-polling events

Tags: box-api

I've been trying to subscribe to the events long-polling endpoint. So first I did an options call to /events and got back the url of a realtime server. However, I can't help noticing that the url looks like this: http://2.realtime.services.box.net/subscribe?channel=XXX&stream_type=all

The url above seems to suggest that I should directly go ahead and try to subscribe to the topic skipping the handshake step. Actually, if I try to handshake at http://2.realtime.services.box.net/ I get back a 400 status code.

I thought about trying to subscribe directly but I also noticed that the channel is at a query param instead of a path param as I would expect.

Could you clarify this? If this really following the comet long-polling standard or is it something else and I try to do this differently? Should I try WebSockets instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Just tried this using websockets and got 400 status code at handshake too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to make a HTTP GET call to the URL that is in the response to the OPTIONS call.   It will respond with a new change once events are available.

There shouldn't be any magic "subscribe" or "websockets" request required.   Simply use a standard HTTP GET.

Each time you call you will open an HTTP connection, and if anything happens on your account, you'll see a {"message":"new_change"} JSON payload flow down the pipe.   If nothing happens, your connection will just timeout and close, or you'll get a 400 error.

As soon as you see the {"message":"new_change"}, that's your signal that it is time to hit the /events API with stream_position from the most recent event that you've received.

There are many types of events, which you can parse differently by their "event_type".    Most of the event types have enough information in them to apply them as a delta or a diff onto an existing copy of the item that the event applies to.  Every event will have a stream_position which will indicate where it is in the time-stream-continuum.

Look for the "source" section of the JSON to see the object.  These object structures follow all the same structures that are used by all other API calls in our API.  So when you see a "type": "folder" it will have the same structure as any other folder that you'd get in a GET /folders/ID API call